# fixing Redux payload is being console logged in the reducer but in modal says cannot read property of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

was wondering if you guys can help me trouble shoot this:

**in my actions i have:**

```
export const getProduct = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setItemsLoading());
  axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/view/${id}`).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ITEM,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};
```

**and in reducer:**

```
case GET_ITEM:
  console.log(action.payload);
  return {
    ...state,
    /* items: action.payload, */
    singleItem: action.payload,
  };
```

**the console logs the object that i am getting but in my model:**

```
static propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  singleItem: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getProduct('5f4589e4b7b3aa98e4ca79ab')
}

<Label for="name">{this.props.item.name}</Label>
<Input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Product Name" onChange={this.onChange} />
<Label for="description">{this.props.item.description}</Label>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item.singleItem,
  user: state.auth,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
})
```

**theres more but thats enough go to on and i keep getting:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
ProductModal.render
src/components/products/ProductModal.js:65
  62 | <ModalBody>
  63 |     <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  64 |         <FormGroup>
> 65 |             <Label for="name">{this.props.item.name}</Label>
     | ^  66 |             <Input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Product Name" onChange={this.onChange} />
  67 |             <Label for="description">{this.props.item.description}</Label>
  68 |             <Input type="textarea" name="description" id="item" placeholder="description" onChange={this.onChange} />
```

**my payload is:**

```
_id(pin):"5f4589e4b7b3aa98e4ca79ab"
name(pin):"Cajun"
description(pin):"Mouth watering artisan freshly made beef jerky, made with love in Texas! - 8 OZ bag"
creator(pin):"Jenn & James"
imgUrl(pin):"http://dgegergerg.dev/masonsbeef/beef1.jpg"
quantity(pin):20
__v(pin):0
```

its an object

Comment: Can you post what your payload looks like?

Comment: updated to show payload

Comment: You can confirm that your redux state object contains `{item: {singleItem: {} } }` ?

Comment: yep, looking at it in my redux dev tools
item -> singleItem -> object with the info

Comment: You dispatch `setItemsLoading()` but in the component you just assume the item is there, should you not check if the item is loading?